# Angular.js nesting directives without markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's a little challenging to articulate what I'd like to ask, so please bear with me.

I understand that, in Angular.js, directives are sort of the magic behind dynamic markup. What one might have once accomplished strictly via jQuery, one now accomplishes via directives. I understand that Angular's HTML compiler traverses the DOM in search of attributes and/or elements corresponding to programmatic directives and links these elements to their respective directives. What I'm wondering is whether there's a way to accomplish this sort of association along with the generation of directive-bound DOM elements without the need for the directive to first exist within the DOM.

Suppose I have a directive that I'd like to use to build an entire seating chart, with sections, rows, seats, etc. The chart could reflect different seating arrangements based on venue, so the template must be able to dynamically render the chart from data representing every little UI component on the chart. I don't understand how one should go about accomplishing this sort of thing using Angular.

Would it make sense to use a single directive to generate the UI in its entirety, or should I have nested directives? (I'm guessing the latter.) And, if the latter, what is a good way of structuring nested directives in such a way that they do not rely on markup and can be generated programmatically?

Comment: That's a broad question. But it's safe to say nested directives is more manageable than a single directive, especially if the interactions between the model, view, and controller are complex and non-trivial. Without knowing too much about your app, I would say you could create custom (nested) directives, using transclusion and templates, and limit your DOM manipulation to the compile/link function and/or template function

Comment: All right. I'm going to complicate matters still further. The "templates" are SVGs, and dynamically-generated SVGs can't be interpolated into the DOM the way markup can; rather, they must be generated programmatically. So, my "template" is really just JavaScript-generated XML representing SVGs. Each SVG corresponds to some data object and requires event-handling.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single directive sounds reasonable, especially since the contents are dynamic. If there are common parts (such as a title or a legend), you could nest those as directives inside.

So:

```
<mp-seating-chart layout="layout"></mp-seating-chart>
```

Here you are passing the layout to the directive, layout being a complex object describing the seating arrangement.